# How to edit a variable in a different file from where it was declared?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently working on the Alien Invasion project within the book Python Crash Course.  The issue is that the picture of my ship is not moving whenever I press the right arrow key (I removed the code for the left arrow key temporarily).

I know that my function to check for key-press events works as it prints out the expected values whenever the key is pressed and when it's not.

When it's being held down, the flag `movingRight` is changed from its default state of false to true. What should happen then is the variable 'center' is changed by adding a predetermined movement factor to it, then using that to print the ship image in its new position.

However, when I print the state of `movingRight` in the `ship.py` file, it shows that `movingRight` is still `False` even during a `KEY_DOWN` event.

Here is the loop that handles the events and changing the ship state. This is within the main file called `alien_invasion.py`:

```
#Create a new Ship
ship = Ship(aiSettings, screen)

#start the main loop for the game
while True:

    #Check for events that affect the ship
    gf.checkEvents(ship)

    #Update the status of the ship based upon checkEvents()
    ship.update()

    #Update the screen after pulling data from ship.update()
    gf.updateScreen(aiSettings, screen, ship)
```

Below is the `checkEvents()` function in a separate file called `game_functions.py`:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:

            print("Moving Right")
            ship.moveRight = True

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:

            print("Done moving right")
            ship.moveRight = False
```

Lastly, below is the code that edits the position of the ship. This is within `ship.py`:

```
def update(self):

    print("movingRight state is: " + self.movingRight) #movingRight is false during KEY_DOWN event

    #Check for a right move
    if self.movingRight:

        #Update the ship's center to the right x amount of pixels
        self.center += self.aiSettings.shipSpeedFactor


    self.rect.centerx = self.center
```

I understand that this book is a few years old now, so could it be that the method I'm using is outdated?

Comment: You can reference (module-level) global variables in other files through their module name. i.e.after an `import alien_invasion`, you could access (and change) the value of `alien_invasion.ship.moveRight`.

Comment: `moveRight` <-> `movingRight`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see in your code, it looks like you're using different names for the moving right variables. In your second code snip, you set ship.moveRight to True, but in your third code snip, you're checking if self.movingRight is True. Try changing it so both use .movingRight or both use .moveRight